# How to correctly write a multi-threaded test program

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, rest

I'm trying to write a stress test program to bash our web server.  I'm trying to use threads to simulate multiple people hitting the server.  However, the problem I'm running into is using 1 thread works 99.9% of the time.  2 threads seem to work 10-20% of the time and anything more seems to fail all the time.

Here's a snippet of my code running, trying to generate threads for testing:

```
    public static final MAX = 1; // (or 2, or 100 while testing)
    <snip>
    <snip>

    String newParams = "{ bunch, of, test, parameters }";
    Callable<String> call1;
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Future<String> f1;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    //      newParams = newParams + slight changes each iteration for each thread;
        call1 = new HttpPostClass.HttpPost(url, newParams);
        f1 = pool.submit(call1);
    }
    pool.shutdown();
```

I don't know if it's because I'm re-using the same Callable/Future objects in the loop or if this is caused by my own ignorance/inexperience of multi-threaded programming that's causing this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me.

Comment: you know, there are lots of existing solutions for stress testing websites... (jmeter, loadrunner, grinder come to mind offhand)

Comment: What is HttpPostClass? I notice that [org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) is annotated as not thread safe

Comment: @SLaks - On the Apache webserver logs, I get a Socket is Closed or SocketException message.  The line of code it fails at is where the server side accesses data at a web storage service.  I checked the code and there's no static class variable so I don't think there should be problems with multiple threads accessing the service.

Comment: @jtahlborn - I didn't think about those tools.  I finished implementing the server side and got curious with the client side and found a code snippet for REST methods of GET and POST and thought I’d help our QA group out.  I’ll still attempt to write this program to play around with threads and REST.  I’ll mention those tools to the QA guys.

Comment: @JacksonOwens - HttpPostClass is a class with code for making POST requests.  I can post the code if you want to see it but it’s just code I found on the web.  Since it doesn’t work with multiple threads, I assume it’s not thread-safe.  Time for me to figure out what thread safe code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load test a web-server, look at the simple but powerful ab: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html